# Unable to get current User Identity details instantly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In an MVC5 project, I'm trying to get `User.Identity` details right after calling `AuthenticationManager.SignIn` method. At that time it's providing empty values instantly. But after redirecting to another actoer for 1 or 2 times it's providing  expected details.

Here is my code in `SignInAsync`

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

And from here I'm calling that method from a controller action via a service class.

```
if (await accountService.LoginAsync(model))
{
    var user = User.Identity.Name; //Here value is showing ""
}
```

But after redirecting to another action, this same code returning the current logged in username. Is there any reason to do that?

Comment: very curious , why do you feel the need to return the Login identity async?

Comment: try this HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: This has been asked several times before. Authentication happens **after** returning to the client and when the client calls the server again. This is because the Cookies can only be read after being sent by the client, which happens after you return those Cookies to them.